# valores en grafica de barras jpgraph v4.3.1

Tags: php7, codeigniter-3, fpdf

Hola Amantes de la programación, tengo el siguiente problema con la libreria jpgraph v4.3.1 deseo colocar los valores arriba de cada barra pero no me muestra nada este es mi código.
necesito su ayuda

[image: Imagen de código]

```
$data1y=$cantMasc;
$data2y=$cantFem;
$maximo = max(max($data1y,$data2y))+10;
$graph = new Graph(650, 305, "auto");
$graph->SetScale("textlin"); 
$graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_NORMAL,9);
$graph->yaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_NORMAL,9);
$graph->xgrid->Show();
$graph->ygrid->SetFill(false);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($tipoResultado);
$graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL, FS_BOLD, 10);
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);
$graph->yaxis->scale->SetAutoMax($maximo);
$graph->SetBox(false);
$b1plot = new BarPlot($data1y);
$b1plot->SetLegend("Masculino");
$b1plot->value->Show();
$b1plot->SetCenter(0.4);
$b2plot = new BarPlot($data2y);
$b2plot->SetLegend("Femenino");
$b2plot->value->Show();
$gbplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($b1plot,$b2plot));
@unlink(APPPATH."../assets/images/$nomGraf.png");        
$graph->Add($gbplot);
$graph->legend->Pos(0.5, 0.99, 'center', 'bottom');
$graph->legend->SetFont(FF_ARIAL, FS_BOLD, 11);        
$graph->Stroke(APPPATH."../assets/images/$nomGraf.png");
$this->Image(APPPATH."../assets/images/$nomGraf.png", 120, 35, 120, 70);
$this->SetAlpha(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

ya logre solucionar este problema de valores en barra con jpgraph
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
public function graficaBarra($nomGraf,$tipoResultado,$cantFem,$cantMasc){
$data1y=$cantMasc;
$data2y=$cantFem;
$maximo = max(max($data1y,$data2y))+10;
$graph = new Graph(650, 305, "auto");
$graph->SetScale("textlin");
$graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_NORMAL,9);
$graph->yaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_NORMAL,9);
$graph->xgrid->Show();
// $theme_class= new UniversalTheme;
// $graph->SetTheme($theme_class);
$graph->ClearTheme();

```
    $graph->SetBox(false);
    $graph->ygrid->SetFill(false);
    $graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($tipoResultado);
    $graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL, FS_BOLD, 10);
    $graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
    $graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);
    $graph->yaxis->scale->SetAutoMax($maximo);
    $graph->yaxis->SetColor("#4a4a4a"); 
    $graph->xaxis->SetColor("#4a4a4a");       
    
    $b1plot = new BarPlot($data1y);
    $b1plot->SetLegend("Masculino");
    $b1plot->SetColor("white");
    $b1plot->SetFillColor("#014F9F"); 
    $b1plot->SetValuePos("top");
    $b1plot->value->SetFont(FF_ARIAL, FS_BOLD, 10);
    $b1plot->value->SetFormat('%d');
    $b1plot->value->Show();

    $b2plot = new BarPlot($data2y);
    $b2plot->SetLegend("Femenino");
    $b2plot->SetColor("white");
    $b2plot->SetFillColor("#DC143C");
    $b2plot->SetValuePos("top");
    $b2plot->value->SetFont(FF_ARIAL, FS_BOLD, 10);
    $b2plot->value->SetFormat('%d'); 
    $b2plot->value->Show();


    $gbplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($b1plot,$b2plot));
    @unlink(APPPATH."../assets/images/$nomGraf.png");
    
    $graph->Add($gbplot);
    $graph->legend->Pos(0.5, 0.99, 'center', 'bottom');
    $graph->legend->SetFont(FF_ARIAL, FS_BOLD, 11); 
    $graph->legend->SetFillColor('#ffffff');
    
    $graph->legend->SetColumns(2);
    $graph->legend->SetFrameWeight(0);
    $graph->SetMarginColor('white');
    $graph->SetColor('white'); 
    $graph->SetFrame(true,'white',0);
    $graph->Stroke(APPPATH."../assets/images/$nomGraf.png");
    $this->Image(APPPATH."../assets/images/$nomGraf.png", 120, 35, 120, 70);
  }
```

Comment: Hola, tengo el mismo problema podrías por favor explicarme como lo hiciste?

Comment: Estoy usando la versión 4.3.4 y no me funciona, como envías los datos?